# How to dynamically add checkboxes using Javascript for parsed data

Tags: javascript

I have this HTML file where if the user clicks on "View questions", it should display the parsed data that I receive. Right now I am working with a JSON test file. It displays the data fine, but I need to dynamically add checkboxes using Javascript for when the data is displayed. And when the user clicks on a checkbox, that data can be sent through Ajax to the backend. How can I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
    <button type=button class="lg=button" id="btn">View questions</button>
        <p id="response"></p>

    <script>
    var resp = document.getElementById("response");
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");


    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json", true);

        xhr.onload = function() {
                if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400) {
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                   var ourData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                   //console.log(ourData);
                    renderHTML(ourData);







                }
        }

        xhr.send();
    });
     function renderHTML(data) {
            var htmlString = "";

            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            htmlString += "<p>" + data[i].name + " is a " + data[i].species + " that likes to eat ";
            }

            htmlString += '.</p>';


        resp.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
     }
</script>
```

Comment: The code you posted already has the clues you need to do this.  Look at renderHTML() for how to add checkboxes.  and xhr.open() for sending information to the server.  Use Google to find tutorials on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It displays the data fine, but I need to dynamically add checkboxes using Javascript for when the data is displayed you need to put input type checkbox while rendering it

```
<input id="checkBox" type="checkbox">
```

You can add event listener to do any logic based on click event on those checkbox.

```js
var resp = document.getElementById("response");
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");


    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json", true);

        xhr.onload = function() {
                if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400) {
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                   var ourData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                   //console.log(ourData);
                    renderHTML(ourData);







                }
        }

        xhr.send();
    });
     function renderHTML(data) {
            var htmlString = "";

            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            htmlString += "<p><input  type='checkbox'>" + data[i].name + " is a " + data[i].species + " that likes to eat ";
            }

            htmlString += '.</p>';


        resp.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
     }
```

```html
<button type=button class="lg=button" id="btn">View questions</button>
        <p id="response"></p>
```